# Custom font icon and Simple-line-icons differ

Tags: css, svg, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I use **Simple Line Icons** on a web site. Now I need to use custom icon that is missing from the above mentioned package. I have SVG file sent by designer, but when I convert this file to font type (ttf, woff, eot etc.) I do get different visual appearance for the same font-size and line-height.
How can I convert it so that it would look similar to the icons in **Simple Line Icons** set? Do I need custom font creation software for that? To compare and adjust glyph properties?

FYI I converted SVG file and created custom font set with the help of icomoon.io app.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an issue with scaling the SVG to size in relation to the other glyphs in the font.

You can try a font editing tool, such as: "FontForge" (https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) to achieve this accurately.

Make sure the SVG glyph is well constructed though, by checking that the vertices are closed properly, not too complex, etc, as it may help with conversion & rendering.

### Edit:

Also check the size of the SVG glyph in relation to the SVG element size. If the glyph is too large (or too small) to fit relatively well inside the width & height parameters of the containing SVG element (document) - (used as glyph box-size) then you will have issues with its size relative to the other glyphs in the font.

Comment: The answer is updated; see latest edition as shown above.

Comment: Used FontForge to adjust font glyph. Thanks.